# How to copy data from 2 cells from workbook A and copy to workbook B in a cell and how do I start a for loop until last row/column

Tags: excel, vba

I have two questions

- How to combine data using two of the cells from workbookA and copy to workbookB on the same cell?
- How do I start using for loop to copy it until the last row/column?

I have no clue on how to combine the data and I do not know where to place the variable inside the code for it to loop until its last column.

```
Dim Tlastrow As Integer
Tlastrow = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

 For r = 1 To Tlastrow
Workbooks("InputB.xls").Worksheets("HC_MODULAR_BOARD_20180112").Range("F3:G3").Copy _
        Workbooks("Output.xls").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("I3")
Next
```

Comment: Your `Tlastrow` variable name is confusing - `Tlastcolumn` would be a better fit.  It's also not clear what your loop should be doing, so a little more explanation would help here: for example what are the first couple of  source/destination ranges?

Comment: For example in F3 "MURATA" and G3 G"RM188R71H104KA93D" are the data that are needed to be copy over to another workbook in I3.

Comment: Merging F3 and G3 together and copy in another workbook in I3

Comment: @TimWilliams I want them to be copied downwards F3 and G3 copied then paste in I3 afterwards copy F4 and G4 and paste in I4. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Paste()

    Dim wsInput As Worksheet, wsOutput As Worksheet, LastRow As Long, C As Range

    Set wsInput = Workbooks("InputB.xls").Worksheets("HC_MODULAR_BOARD_20180112")
    Set wsOutput = Workbooks("Output.xls").Worksheets("Sheet1")

    With wsInput
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row 'Last Row with data
        For Each C In .Range("F3:F" & LastRow) 'loop for every row with data
            wsOutput.Cells(C.Row, "I").Value = C & " " & C.Offset(0, 1)
        Next C
    End With

End Sub
```

This code is assuming you want to paste every row from your input workbook to the output workbook on the same rows, but merging F and G columns. It's just pasting the values, not formulas or formats.

Comment: Hi Damian thank you for your help. I actually have other more stuffs to copy can you elaborate about the looping? So I can change accordingly.

Comment: And Damian how do I loop these? I need to set the whole column to 01 and have to copy first character of the cell and paste into another cell




 'Workbooks("Output.xls").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F3").Value = _
        Left(Workbooks("InputA.xls").Worksheets("Sheet0").Range("G3").Value, 1)


'Workbooks("Output.xls").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("G3").Value = "01"

Comment: I'm looping from F3 to F and the last row with data. It will take both the F cell and the G cell to the same row it is taking data from, but on cell I for the output workbook.

Comment: Please kindly look at the 2nd comment thank you so much